# How to resolve this "org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 401" error of SonarQube quality gates

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube

I have this error on SonarQube quality gates:

> org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 401

I'm getting above error during third stage build pipeline in Jenkins.

SonarQube Scanner version: 4.5.0.2216

SonarQube Server version: 8.6.0.39681

Jenkins Server version: 2.235.5

Below is my build pipeline

```
node {
  stage('Clone the Git') {
    git 'https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples'
  }
  stage('SonarQube analysis') {
    def scannerHome = tool 'sonarqube';
    withSonarQubeEnv('sonarqube-server') {
      sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner \
      -D sonar.login=admin \
      -D sonar.password=admin \
      -D sonar.projectKey=sonarqubetest3 \
      -D sonar.exclusions=vendor/**,resources/**,**/*.java \
      -D sonar.host.url=http://192.168.0.4:9000/"
    }
  }
  stage('Quality Gates'){
      
     timeout(time: 1, unit: 'HOURS') {
    def qg = waitForQualityGate() 
    if (qg.status != 'OK') {
      error "Pipeline aborted due to quality gate failure: ${qg.status}"
    }
  }
      
  }
}
```

Below is the complete Jenkins job log:

```
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonar-qube-testing
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Clone the Git)
[Pipeline] git
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.11.0'
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanning-examples +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 1cbdd40467f475fcdbd8367ca00b65acbf774e3f (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 1cbdd40467f475fcdbd8367ca00b65acbf774e3f # timeout=10
 > git branch -a -v --no-abbrev # timeout=10
 > git branch -D master # timeout=10
 > git checkout -b master 1cbdd40467f475fcdbd8367ca00b65acbf774e3f # timeout=10
Commit message: "Merge pull request #99 from SonarSource/pre-8.x-hardening"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 1cbdd40467f475fcdbd8367ca00b65acbf774e3f # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (SonarQube analysis)
[Pipeline] tool
[Pipeline] withSonarQubeEnv
Injecting SonarQube environment variables using the configuration: sonarqube-server
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonarqube/bin/sonar-scanner -D sonar.login=admin -D sonar.password=admin -D sonar.projectKey=sonarqubetest3 -D sonar.exclusions=vendor/**,resources/**,**/*.java -D sonar.host.url=http://192.168.0.4:9000
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonarqube/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: SonarScanner 4.5.0.2216
INFO: Java 1.8.0_242 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Linux 4.15.0-111-generic amd64
INFO: User cache: /var/jenkins_home/.sonar/cache
INFO: Scanner configuration file: /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/sonarqube/conf/sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: NONE
INFO: Analyzing on SonarQube server 8.6.0
INFO: Default locale: "en", source code encoding: "UTF-8" (analysis is platform dependent)
WARN: SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=658ms
INFO: Server id: BF41A1F2-AXaTGa1I2xlvXb1FgNjK
INFO: User cache: /var/jenkins_home/.sonar/cache
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=602ms
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=649ms
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Process project properties (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Project key: sonarqubetest3
INFO: Base dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonar-qube-testing
INFO: Working dir: /var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonar-qube-testing/.scannerwork
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'sonarqubetest3'
INFO: Load project settings for component key: 'sonarqubetest3' (done) | time=574ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=636ms
INFO: Auto-configuring with CI 'Jenkins'
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=10366ms
INFO: Indexing files...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO:   Excluded sources: vendor/**, resources/**, **/*.java
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=573ms
INFO: 105 files indexed
INFO: 12 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
INFO: Quality profile for cs: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for flex: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for js: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for kotlin: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for php: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for py: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for web: Sonar way
INFO: Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on module sonarqubetest3
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=600ms
INFO: Sensor Python Sensor [python]
INFO: Starting global symbols computation
INFO: 9 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Starting rules execution
INFO: 9 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 9/9 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor Python Sensor [python] (done) | time=6536ms
INFO: 9/9 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor Cobertura Sensor for Python coverage [python]
INFO: Sensor Cobertura Sensor for Python coverage [python] (done) | time=23ms
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python]
INFO: Sensor PythonXUnitSensor [python] (done) | time=8ms
INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily]
INFO: 2 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 2/2 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor CSS Rules [cssfamily] (done) | time=1624ms
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
INFO: 'sonar.coverage.jacoco.xmlReportPaths' is not defined. Using default locations: target/site/jacoco/jacoco.xml,target/site/jacoco-it/jacoco.xml,build/reports/jacoco/test/jacocoTestReport.xml
INFO: No report imported, no coverage information will be imported by JaCoCo XML Report Importer
INFO: Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=6ms
INFO: Sensor Kotlin Sensor [kotlin]
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Sensor Kotlin Sensor [kotlin] (done) | time=902ms
INFO: Sensor KotlinSurefireSensor [kotlin]
INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
INFO: parsing [/var/jenkins_home/workspace/sonar-qube-testing/target/surefire-reports]
INFO: Sensor KotlinSurefireSensor [kotlin] (done) | time=5ms
INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript]
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Version of TypeScript used during analysis: 3.8.3
INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor JavaScript analysis [javascript] (done) | time=4872ms
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp]
INFO: Sensor C# Properties [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
INFO: 8 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=396ms
INFO: 8/8 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor HTML [web]
INFO: Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=80ms
INFO: Sensor Flex [flex]
INFO: 2 source files to be analyzed
INFO: Sensor Flex [flex] (done) | time=107ms
INFO: 2/2 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor Flex Cobertura [flex]
INFO: No Cobertura report provided (see 'sonar.flex.cobertura.reportPaths' property)
INFO: Sensor Flex Cobertura [flex] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
INFO: 8 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 8/8 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=182ms
INFO: Sensor PHP sensor [php]
INFO: Starting PHP symbol indexer
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
INFO: Starting PHP rules
INFO: 1 source files to be analyzed
INFO: 1/1 source files have been analyzed
INFO: No PHPUnit test report provided (see 'sonar.php.tests.reportPath' property)
INFO: No PHPUnit coverage reports provided (see 'sonar.php.coverage.reportPaths' property)
INFO: Sensor PHP sensor [php] (done) | time=353ms
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php]
INFO: Sensor Analyzer for "php.ini" files [php] (done) | time=2ms
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet]
INFO: Sensor VB.NET Properties [vbnet] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: ------------- Run sensors on project
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp]
WARN: No protobuf reports found. The C# files will not have highlighting and metrics.
WARN: No Roslyn issue reports were found. The C# files have not been analyzed.
WARN: Your project contains C# files which cannot be analyzed with the scanner you are using. To analyze C# or VB.NET, you must use the Scanner for MSBuild 4.x, see https://redirect.sonarsource.com/doc/install-configure-scanner-msbuild.html
INFO: Sensor C# [csharp] (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
INFO: Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=16ms
INFO: CPD Executor 7 files had no CPD blocks
INFO: CPD Executor Calculating CPD for 8 files
INFO: CPD Executor CPD calculation finished (done) | time=28ms
INFO: Analysis report generated in 135ms, dir size=189 KB
INFO: Analysis report compressed in 77ms, zip size=70 KB
INFO: Analysis report uploaded in 581ms
INFO: ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http://192.168.0.4:9000/dashboard?id=sonarqubetest3
INFO: Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
INFO: More about the report processing at http://192.168.0.4:9000/api/ce/task?id=AXbH8OKO2xlvXb1FgSam
INFO: Analysis total time: 37.408 s
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION SUCCESS
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 39.822s
INFO: Final Memory: 93M/761M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withSonarQubeEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Quality Gates)
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 1 min 0 sec
[Pipeline] timeout
Timeout set to expire in 1 hr 0 min
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] waitForQualityGate
Checking status of SonarQube task 'AXbH8OKO2xlvXb1FgSam' on server 'sonarqube-server'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // timeout
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
org.sonarqube.ws.client.HttpException: Error 401 on http://192.168.0.4:9000/api/ce/task?id=AXbH8OKO2xlvXb1FgSam : 
    at org.sonarqube.ws.client.BaseResponse.failIfNotSuccessful(BaseResponse.java:36)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.HttpClient.getHttp(HttpClient.java:38)
    at hudson.plugins.sonar.client.WsClient.getCETask(WsClient.java:51)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.checkTaskCompleted(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:234)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.jenkins.pipeline.WaitForQualityGateStep$Execution.start(WaitForQualityGateStep.java:171)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeStep(DSL.java:286)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:179)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1239.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1213)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1022)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:163)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.GroovyInterceptor.onMethodCall(GroovyInterceptor.java:23)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:157)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:135)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:19)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1236.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatch(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:55)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.CollectionLiteralBlock$ContinuationImpl.item(CollectionLiteralBlock.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1659.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I know "Error 401" means wrong credentials/unauthorized but same creds are working at second stage "SonarQube Analysis" of job build.

I have also added webhooks URL for Jenkins in SonarQube server as "http://192.168.0.4:8056/sonarqube-webhook/" but to no avail.

What can I try next?

Comment: have you able to fix this using withSonarQubeEnv tag? I added this but still having same error.

Answer (score 1):

When you use the "withSonarQubeEnv" pipeline step, it is expected that the string value provided matches the name of the SonarQube instance configured in Jenkins.  In that configuration will be defined the sonarqube login credentials.  If that string matches the SonarQube instance name, then the login credentials will be put into environment variables.

However, I believe this usually only expects to use the "token" authentication method, not the old-style "login" and "password" values.  In the "token" method, the "SONAR_AUTH_TOKEN" environment variable is set to the "sonar.login" property, and the "sonar.password" value is just not set.

In fact, I don't believe the "task" api used inside the "waitForQualityGate" step can use anything but the "token" authentication method.  To get this to work, you'll need to define a token value, and set that inside the Jenkins configuration for the SonarQube instance.

Although we don't do it this way in our builds, I believe if you call the "waitForQualityGate" step INSIDE the "withSonarQubeEnv" step, that will put the proper authentication token into the environment variable so "waitForQualityGate" can see it.

It's very handy to run a "sh" step, running the "env" command line, so you can see what variables are set in the environment at any particular time.

It's also good to read the "sonar-scanner" reference, which talks about these steps, at https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline .

Answer (score 0):

use this

withSonarQubeEnv(credentialsId: 'your token')

Comment: David's answer already provided this information, and you don't provide additional info.